# Java - I want to draw multiple 2D Ellipses using a timer, but it's not working

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d, ellipse

Already tried searching, but couldn't find anything.

I'm trying to draw multiple 2D Ellipses using an array, and a for loop, I'm repainting the frame every second. The thing is, I only get one Ellipse everytime I repaint, can somebody tell me what's wrong with me code, please?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MovingDot extends JFrame{
    static int posX = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*780);
    static int posY = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*780);
    static int width = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*780);
    static int height = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*780);
    static int dots = 0;
    public static Timer timer;

    public MovingDot(){
        super("Moving Dot");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800, 800);

        Dot2 dot = new Dot2();
        add(dot);

        setVisible(true);
        timer = new Timer((int)Math.round((1000)), timerAction);
        timer.start();
    }

    private ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            posX = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*780);
            posY = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*780);
            width = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*780);
            height = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*780);

            float r = (float)Math.random();
            float g = (float)Math.random();
            float b = (float)Math.random();

            Color col = new Color(r,g,b);

            setBackground(col);

            dots++;

            repaint();
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new MovingDot();
            }
        });
    }
}


class Dot2 extends JPanel{

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics c2){
        int x = MovingDot.posX;
        int y = MovingDot.posY;
        int w = MovingDot.width;
        int h = MovingDot.height;

        float r,g,b;

        Color col;

        Graphics2D c = (Graphics2D) c2;

        c.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        Ellipse2D.Float[] e = new Ellipse2D.Float[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                r = (float)Math.random();
            else
                r = 0.163F;
            g = (float)Math.random();
            b = (float)Math.random();

            col = new Color(r,g,b);

            c.setColor(col);
            e[i] = new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, w, h);
            c.fill(e[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Found out what was wrong myself, I had to make x, y, w and h random in my paintComponent. And no, this is not for a school assignment, I'm trying to teach myself Java using a book.

And about making my methods static, I was planning on using them in my JPanel, but I realised I don't need them, so I'm going to delete them. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You shouldn't be creating your Ellipse array inside of paintComponent, makes no sense.
- Instead create the array in the class.
- Your JPanel's paintComponent method should not have any program logic in it. It should only have code that paints the ellipses. That is, it should iterate through your array with a for loop, and if the item in the array is not null draw it.
- You'd be even better off using an `ArrayList<Ellipse2D>` and not an array. That way you wouldn't have to check for nulls.
- In the Timer's ActionListener, if your counter is < 10, you'd add an Ellipse2D to the array and call repaint.
- If the counter >= 10 you'd stop the Timer
- Also, none of your static variables should be static, and having them as static suggests that the program design is off. If this is for a school assignment, that could lead to deduction of your grade.